# Vfs global is not showing document upload step, applying for uk visa from USA

Tags: uk, tourist-visas, vfs-global

I submitted the application for uk visa for me and my son. After that registered on vfsglobal.co.uk, added both our reference number, uploaded a couple documents, and clicked continue button, which took me to select the shipping options. I want to upload more documents, but its not showing the documents upload option any more. I am not able to find any help or contact number for VFSglobal. Any help on how to upload documents to my application would be really appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I am having the same issue have you got the solution for that yet?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this VFS tech help request needs to be directed to VFS